# Parsing values in dictionary to a list in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want to convert the existing JSON in the column:

```
namedTags = [{"rid":"ri.compass..ae1","name":"reservoir"},     
{"rid":"ri.compass..ed18","name":cave"},      
{"rid":"ri.compass..c97","name":"staging"}]
```

I want to collect only the name into a list

The expected output in new column:

```
['reservoir','cave','staging']
```

Dataframe looks like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1TAv.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was able to slove by some dirty way, i know its not optimal.

```
#exploded into rows
df = df.withColumn("crid", explode(col("nTags")))

#clenaed up using regex
    df= df.withColumn('crid', regexp_replace('crid', '.*(?="name")', ''))
    df= df.withColumn('crid', regexp_replace('crid', '"name":', ''))
    df= df.withColumn('crid', regexp_replace('crid', '\}', ''))

#used this to get the desired form
df=df.groupby('objectRid','taginfo','name',"namedTags").agg(collect_list('crid').alias("tags"))
     df = df.withColumn("tags", concat_list("tags"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['col'] = df['some_other_col'].apply(lambda row: [x.get('name',0) for x in row] )
```

Comment: how exactly i need to use this, updated pic for reference

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have array of objects in the column. You can use `transform` to extract `name` key from each object:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([[[{"rid":"ri.compass..ae1","name":"reservoir"},
                              {"rid":"ri.compass..ed18","name":"cave"},
                              {"rid":"ri.compass..c97","name":"staging"}]]], ['namedTags'])


df.withColumn('name', f.expr("transform(namedTags, el -> el.name)")).show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|           namedTags|                name|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[[name -> reservo...|[reservoir, cave,...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use list comprehension.
Check below code:

```
lst = [{"rid":"ri.compass..ae1","name":"reservoir"},{"rid":"ri.compass..ed18","name":"cave"},{"rid":"ri.compass..c97","name":"staging"}]
names = [i['name'] for i in lst]
print(names)
```

output:

```
['reservoir', 'cave', 'staging']
```

Comment: thank you, trying in pyspark, any inputs  are welcome

Comment: @Nishanth please share your existing code so that I can help.

Comment: def my_compute_function(ctx, my_input, write_output):
    df = my_input.dataframe()

###calls an API with json response##
    df = df.withColumn("tags", tag_list(df["objectRid"]))
    
    df = df.select( 'objectRid','tags', F.json_tuple('tags', 'name', 'namedTags').alias('name', 'namedTags'))       

    write_output.write_dataframe(df)